# leave gap before and after \hrule

Tags: spacing, rules

I'm using `\hrule` to draw a line that has the width of the text.

Is there a safe way to leave a gap before and after the line?

The plain code is:

```
blablabla
\hrule
blabla
```

And produces:
[image]

Coming closer to what I need is:

```
blablabla \\
\hrule
blabla
```

Which produces:
[image]

And, of course, I get error messages when I try:

```
blablabla \\
\hrule
\\ blabla
```

Comment: `\hrule`, probably. Can you add an example of how you use it?

Comment: Before and after you mean inline? Or a gap before means above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to avoid using `\\` just end the paragraph and add space:

```
aaaaa

\vspace{1cm}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}

aaaaaaa
```

If you want a spaced out line.